# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded while truncating tables

Tags: java, oracle

I get this exception while truncating all table in a schema.
I truncate 3 schema in my Java code and first method get list of table names from given schema name and second method executes **"TRUNCATE TABLE table_name"** query.
I confused about my code always succesful while truncating first and third schema. But while executing on second schema I get **ORA-01000** error.
My truncate code is

```
    private void truncateTable(Connection conn, String tableName) {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(Utility.TRUNCATE_TABLE + tableName);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("SQLException occured while getting table names from schema", e);
    } finally {
        Utility.free(ps, null, null);
    }
}


    private List<String> getAllTableNames(Connection conn) {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(Utility.SELECT_ALL_TABLE_NAMES);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            list.add(rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("SQLException occured while getting table names from schema", e);
    } finally {
        Utility.free(ps, rs, null);
    }
    return list;
}

    public static void free(PreparedStatement ps, ResultSet rs, Connection conn) {
    if (rs != null) {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Error occurred while closing ResultSet",e);
        }
    }
    if (ps != null) {
        try {
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Error occurred while closing PreparedStatement",e);
        }
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Error occurred while closing Connection",e);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the wrong about code or is it about schema configuraiton in Oracle?
How can I solve this?

Comment: Make sure you are closing all these result sets when you get the table names.

Comment: Yes sure I added my code and after exception truncates tables of other other schema succesfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If are you iterating over the List generated by `getAllTableNames` and calling `truncateTable` in a tight loop, your `free` calls in the `finally` block might just be delayed and stacking up to an extent that they aren't clearing fast enough for the next iterations - since  you only know the `finally` will be called at some point, not necessarily immediately and before control is returned to the caller.

The schema size would make a difference to that, so it might make sense that a small schema succeeds and a large one fails. If that is what's happening then you should call `free` inside the `try`, as well as in the `finally`:

```
    private void truncateTable(Connection conn, String tableName) {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(Utility.TRUNCATE_TABLE + tableName);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        Utility.free(ps, null, null);
        ps = null;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("SQLException occured while getting table names from schema", e);
    } finally {
        if (ps != null) {
            Utility.free(ps, null, null);
        }
    }
}
```

If `Utility.free` checks whether `ps` is null then that check in the `finally` block might be redundant, but without it, `free` would be called twice if there is no `SQLException`.

Comment: yes Alex I iterate over the List and Utility.free method checks if ps isn't null it close ps inside method.

Comment: Occured error in schema many tables. More than 50 table but other successful schemas each has 10 table. Maybe it causes error.

Comment: @Ugur - does moving the `free` inside the `try` resolve the problem? If you're freeing properly in that call then the schema size should stop being relevant. Just as another thought, does `free` actually release `ps` even if `rs` is null?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. I think it is about schema. Because I always get same error and same schema.

Comment: @Ugur - I can only think that `free` isn't working as expected; maybe you can add the code for that method to the question (*not* as a comment)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code and make sure you are closing the cursors after being used. If the problem still persists please set OPEN_CURSORS to some more value.

Comment: then please set open cursors to some more value for the time being it will help you